# Azure DevOps to build sqlproj to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to set up my build pipeline in azure devops (using azure-pipelines.yml) but I'm unable to set it up correctly. I want the pipeline to build the SQLPROJ (SSDT) project, which is done fine (it produces a dll and I need a dacpac, but that's another story), but my real problem here is that I cannot configure it to copy this .dll/.dacpac to the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).

I tried several things, here are two of them that didn't work. It seems to me it ignores the msbuildArgs.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build AlmaDb - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    solution: 'AlmaDb/AlmaDb.sqlproj'
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I tried with these, but still no luck:

```
msbuildArgs: '/p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
```

Did anyone else face this problem?

Comment: hm, I have pretty much the same config which works for regular build, try changing `MSBuild@1` to `VSBuild@1`?

Comment: OutDir ? try using OutputPath instead

Comment: @4c74356b41 - your suggestion of changing from MSBuild@1 to VSBuild@1 worked! Thanks!